# Animation mouse

Tags: animation, dopesheet

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U1Vju66vyQ help pls. the green line in the dopesheet moves wrong and not with my mouse. i want to select keyframe 40 for example, but i can only select keyframe 39 and 41. it skips some keyframes. why? it is my complet problem. anyone help pls. i tried to start blender new and delete animation but it still does not work. PLS i need to continue my work

Comment: I think that you should totally rephrase your question. As it is now, I think it won't be answered. Add details, screenshots, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you use time remapping. Use this feature carefully, especially with animation.
To restore the default behavior, reset the time values to 100.

[image]

If you want to make your animation slower or faster, I would recommend to scale the keyframes in the dopesheet or in the graph editor.